# How can we set chart settings for number abbreviations of Data Studio Report?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, looker-studio

Date and number abbreviations in Data Studio Report look different on different users. In English, abbreviation of 1000 is K and abbreviation of 1,000,000,000 is B. But In Turkish, abbreviation of 1000 is B. 
This causes confusion between a thousand or a billion. When examined users with different report views, we found that Google Account Language Settings are different.Is it possible set these abbreviations so that they do not change with the Google Account Language Settings?[image: diffrent abbreviations chart]

Answer (score 1):

The number format is based on the language of the respective Google Account that's logged in by the viewer. To display the Report URL in a specific language (e.g. English), add the suffix:

```
?hl=en
```

[More Language Codes](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/languages)

**1) Standard URL**

> https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/48900f64-2068-4331-b707-f82df114542a

**2) English (US)**

> https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/48900f64-2068-4331-b707-f82df114542a?hl=en

**3) Spanish**

> https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/48900f64-2068-4331-b707-f82df114542a?hl=es

Source: [Google Forum Post (Nimantha 13 Jan 2020)](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/11486612?hl=en&msgid=25480042)